# Can I store multiple databases in an application's database folder?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I was having an SQLite database with size less than 1 MB in the asset folder. I am copying this database to the applications default database folder on application launch. It was working fine. Now the database has grown and due to limitations with the Asset folder, I am not able to copy the database from Asset folder to the application.

Is there any way to manage multiple databases in application? If yes, what will be the methods to query them separately? Please share some good link for such database queries.

Comment: I don't think it would be best option to have multiple database. Best choice may be having external database (hosted on internet).

Answer (score 0):

Change your db file's suffix to media file type, such like yourdb.mpg . then you won't be limited by 1mb size, and you can copy it to data/your.packge/database folder when your app first run.